# Doing a Google Maps reverse geocode and displaying the result as part as HTML content inside an infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I have put together this script (*note: I'm using jQuery 1.11.2*) that gets lat long coordinates from a PHP operation (used for something else) and displays a map with a customized marker and infowindow that includes HTML for formatting the information that is displayed.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maplat = 41.36058;
    var maplong = 2.19234;

    function initialize() { 
        // Create a Google coordinate object for where to center the map
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( maplat, maplong ); // Coordinates    

        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 3,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

        // CREATE AN INFOWINDOW FOR THE MARKER
        var content = 'This will show up inside the infowindow and it is here where I would like to show the converted lat/long coordinates into the actual, human-readable City/State/Country'
        ;  // HTML text to display in the InfoWindow

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content,maxWidth: 250
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker( { 
            position: latlng,     
            map: map,
            title: "A SHORT BUT BORING TITLE",
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to do a reverse geocode on the coordinates stored in the latlng variable and get back the results of that in a "City, State, Country" format and insert that into the HTML for the informarker stored in the "content" variable.

Have tried multiple approaches without success. *Please note that I've deliberately left out the reverse geocoding script I tried to use for clarity purposes.*

**Edit:** I've adjusted the script presented here to comply with the rules about it being clear, readable and that it actually should work. I also include a link to a CodePen so that you can see it in action: [Script on CodePen](http://codepen.io/webneticos/pen/XbzREq)

Regarding including the script for reverse geocoding, what I did was a disaster, only breaking the page and producing "undefined value" errors. I'd like to learn the correct way of doing this by example, and that's where the wonderful StackOverflow community comes in. Thanks again for your interest in helping me out.

Comment: Can you expand on how it's not working? What does happen?

Comment: You left out the code that isn't working? You do realize the geocoder (and reverse geocoder) are asynchronous?

Comment: Just to make sure, when you try to print `maplat` and `maplong` to console what do you get? Whay I'm trying to point out is are you doing async calls correctly?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @JustinY ; the value I'm storing comes back as undefined.

Comment: @geocodezip I think that fact escapes me completely, including its meaning.

Comment: @Hamed I'm getting the correct latitude/longitude coordinates. The map that gets displayed as part of the script shows the correct location. No problem with that.

Comment: @geocodezip did as you requested. See the edits in the original post.

Comment: Regardless of how much of a "disaster" your code was, posting your best attempt would avoid all the answers that don't actually work for you.

Comment: @geocodezip I understand what you are saying but there are things best left in a text editor somewhere...

Comment: A big thank you to hamed, geocodezip, JustinY and Dr-Molle and to all for trying to help me with this. I was able to solve it. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
function reverseGeocoder(lat, lng, callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
    geocoder.geocode({"latLng" : point }, function(data, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && data[0]) {
            callback(null, data[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
            console.log("Error: " + status);
            callback(status, null);
        }
    });
};
```

And basically you would call the function like:

```
reverseGeocoder(lat, lng, function(err, result){
    // Do whatever has to be done with result!
    // EDIT: For example you can pass the result to your initialize() function like so:
    initialize(result); // And then inside your initialize function process the result!
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hamed. However, I'm getting a "unexpected token" in CodePen, "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' on the Console.

Comment: @AdminWC check again, I had miss typed `callback` instead of `function` inside the second code block

Comment: I can confirm the error is gone. However, I have to confess I'm having a hard time with the "do whatever has to be done with result".

I was sccessful on being able to see the correctly reverse geocode info in a alert box, but outside that, I can't figure out how to get it outside the reverseGeocoder "realm"/function and place it where I really need it.

Any guidance or words of wisdom?

Comment: @AdminWC see my edits - javascript is a async language unlike php or any other this would mean that instructions are ran on a single thread one after another without waiting for their latter!

Comment: I implemented your edits but still can't make that darn reverse geo-coded text (the actual address) displayed as simple text. The initialize(result); causes the map to refresh twice and trying to use either "result" as a way to display the address as text inside the infowindow has proven fruitless.

Comment: @AdminWC the fact that the map is refreshed twice is that maybe you have initialized the map twice. I would have done it this way -> <<Draw an empty map -> reverse Geocode -> inside the callback set info-window options -> draw you marker on the map (but don't re-draw the map).>> This way I think there wouldn't be any problems. I haven't seen all of your code, and further continuing this discussion would be off topic. If you have other problems I suggest you to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a node instead of a string as `content` , then you may place the geocoding-result inside the content, no matter if the infoWindow is already visible or not or when the result is available(it doesn't even matter if the InfoWindow has already been initialized, a node is always "live").

Simple Demo:

```js
function initialize() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.42520);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 18,
      center: latlng
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latlng
    }),
    content = document.createElement('div'),
    infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });
  content.innerHTML = '<address>the address should appear here</address>';
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWin.open(map, this);
  });
  geocoder.geocode({
    location: latlng
  }, function(r, s) {
    if (s === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      content.getElementsByTagName('address')[0].textContent = r[0].formatted_address;
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }

  });
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html,
      body,
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work because of all the custom HTML that is being used inside infoWindow.

Can the results of the reverse geocoding be obtained in its simplest, purest form without resorting to Google Maps API calls to create the DIVs and all the HTML that needs to be displayed inside the infoWindow?

Comment: When you need more custom HTML, put it into the node(content), the only thing you need to make it work(placing the geocode-result inside the content) is a node inside the content that may be referenced(via `getElementsByTagName` in my demo, may also be done via e.g. `queryselector` or any other method that is suitable to access a child/grandchild of a node )